# Lottie with user interaction on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, lottie

In my iOS app I have lottie animation, which is on the whole screen. During animation user interactions are not available. I want to make everything under animation active to user interaction (scroll, buttons, etc.) 
Is there any chance to do it?

CODE:

```
guard let mainView = self?.view, let animationView = LOTAnimationView(name: "someName") else { return }

animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                             y: 0,
                         width: mainView.frame.size.width,
                        height: mainView.frame.size.height)

animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
animationView.loopAnimation = false

mainView.addSubview(animationView)

animationView.play() { _ in
    animationView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet disabling user interaction for the animation view would do the trick. Try something like:
`animationView.userInteractionEnabled = false`. This should prevent touches from being consumed by the `animationView` and not being propagated down the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried adding gesture recognizers to Lottie view ?

Edit after code attach :

you can try add gestureRecognizer to animationView and add parameter (sender) on your function.

```swift
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .ended {
        // handling code
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider tableView under the animation. How to handle tap on cell?

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: Using gesture recognizer on animationView I can handle only tap on the animation. But what when I want to handle tap on one of hundred of buttons, tableviewCells, collectionViewCells under animation view?